# UWSim install problem, Ubuntu 12.04,ROS Groovy

Tags: ros, ubuntu, uwsim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have some problems on using command "rosrun uwsim uwsim" to run uwsim following errors are showing:

```
Jack@Jack:~$ rosrun uwsim uwsim
    Starting UWSim...    
      . Setting localized world: 6.1e-05s    
    Loading URDF robot...    
      · robot/GIRONA500/g500_March11.osg: 2.67438s
      · robot/ARM5E/ARM5E_part0.osg: 0.082435s
      · robot/ARM5E/ARM5E_part1.osg: 0.119529s
      · robot/ARM5E/ARM5E_part2.osg: 0.127205s
      · robot/ARM5E/ARM5E_part3.osg: 0.439133s
      · robot/ARM5E/ARM5E_part4_base.osg: 0.420119s
      · robot/ARM5E/ARM5E_part4_jaw1.osg: 0.065359s
      · robot/ARM5E/ARM5E_part4_jaw2.osg: 0.058875s    
      · Linking links.../opt/ros/groovy/lib/uwsim/uwsim: line 20: 25729 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) rosrun uwsim uwsim_binary --dataPath ~/.uwsim/data $@
```

Thank you for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192619/uwsim-install-problem,-ubuntu-12.04,ros-groovy/) by [Cong Wang](https://answers.ros.org/users/20188/cong-wang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-09-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I will answer this one as it seems the only one "legit", I mean try to post your question in a new question rather than copy-paste it in every single uwsim tagged question please this just causes confusion.

As Miquel answered in other post do you have 3d support in your computer?, and have you tried starting it with --disableShaders option?. Segmentation fault at loading usually means a problem with graphic card/drivers so check if 3d is working.

---

Originally posted by [Javier Perez](https://answers.ros.org/users/3430/javier-perez/) with karma: 486 on 2014-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1